# Custom strtoull functions producing invalid results

Tags: c++

I do not have access to anything like `strtoull` on my actual platform, so I need to find/handroll one. I've tried all four from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320876/is-there-any-alternative-to-strtoull-function-in-c) and they all give me the same, wrong answer, on my windows testing platform. I also tried on online compilers.

One of the functions is

```
unsigned long long strtoull_simple(const char *s) {
  unsigned long long sum = 0;
  while (*s) {
    sum = sum*10 + (*s++ - '0');
  }
  return sum;
}
```

And given "87ddb08343547aec" it produces `9277008343552481` instead of the real value `9790175242790140652` evident [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html) and also evident if you use `strtoull` where available. Why do all of those functions fail to provide the correct value?

Comment: You're not handling the hex digits at all

Comment: The function posted looks to be made to parse decimal numbers; I don't think it will handle hexadecimal values correctly.

Comment: [Note that `strtoull` has a parameter used to specify the base](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul). You need this information in order to know what characters to accept and handle which to reject and halt parsing.

Comment: Thanks guys. I knew I was being stupid, I just couldn't figure out `why`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the code looks like it is for base-10 numbers but the number you are trying to parse looks base-16. You can add a parameter to specify the base:

```
unsigned long long strtoull_simple(const char *s, int base)
{
    unsigned long res = 0;
    while (*s) {
        // TODO: handle invalid chars
        char c = tolower(*s);
        res = (res * base) + (isdigit(c) ? c - '0' : c - 'a' + 10);
        *s++
    }
    return res;
}
```

And call it with

```
printf("%llu", strtoull_simple("87ddb08343547aec", 16));
```

Output:

```
9790175242790140652
```

Comment: Great, just did something almost exactly like that. Can I ask why not use `unsigned char c`? I'm really hung up on chars and them having to be unsigned when it comes to reading hex.. Is this true?

Comment: Since it is dealing with single digits, there are no worries about overflowing the `char`. So `signed` or `unsigned` work. Also, `char` may be `unsigned` by default: [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941)

Comment: Side note: `strtoull` will stop parsing when it finds an invalid character. This needs a bit more checking to replicate that behaviour. Smurf and I'm too blind to see the comment pointing out exactly that.

Comment: `Smurf and I'm too blind to see the comment pointing out exactly that` .. say.. what?